# jQuery/ CSS: Highlight row on click not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table with alternate row colors. Also, on mouse-over, each row is highlighted. I am trying to add a feature when to highlight the row to light green, when the row is clicked, doing this only one row at a time.

The code I started with was pure CSS, and now to add this event, I am adding jQuery.

Unfortunately, I am doing something wrong with the classes, because when I click on the row nothing happens. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong, and help me correct this error?

```
   $(document).ready(function() {

     $('#myTable tr').hover(function() {
       $(this).addClass('hover');
     }, function() {
       $(this).removeClass('hover');
     });

     $('tr').on('click-row', function() {
       $(this).toggleClass('click-row');
     });

   });
```

Here is my development [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/itortu/xeqkb00c/)

I made an error on the fiddle that I included. I am cleaning up the version I was working with and will update it in a couple of minutes. I apologize for the mistake.

**UPDATE**

The table is working very nicely now. I just have one question if possible, how can I avoid having the the yellow highlight applied on the table header?

Many thanks.

Comment: You forgot to add jQuery in your fiddle.

Comment: Also, your fiddle has nothing regarding the click you mention. No jQuery and no CSS.

Comment: I updated the fiddle link. I am sorry for the mistake.

Comment: Shouldn't `.on('click-row', ...)` be `.on('click', ...)`? Is that a copying error, or in your real code?

Comment: That was a mistake I made when copying it. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: @erasmocarlos Don't you think you should fix it now that it has been pointed out?

Comment: I think I already fixed it. https://jsfiddle.net/itortu/xeqkb00c/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With your [**jsFiddle example fixed**](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/xeqkb00c/13/), what you had was close. The issue was with the specificity of your CSS. Change the rule:

```
.hover {
    background-color: #FFFFCC;
}
```

to:

```
tr.hover {
   background-color: #FFFFCC;
}
```

The same goes for your `.click-row` class. You also had the wrong jQuery code for your click event. It should be:

```
$('#myTable tr').hover(function() {
  $(this).addClass('hover');
}, function() {
  $(this).removeClass('hover');
}).on('click', function() {
  $('#myTable tr').not(this).removeClass('click-row')
  $(this).toggleClass('click-row');
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this works well. Question, do you know how to avoid having the the yellow highlight on the table header?

Comment: Sure, like this https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/fatw6f9m/? Change `$('#myTable tr')` to `$('#myTable tbody tr')`

Comment: Awesome. Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Your code works, but your fiddle is wrong:

1. You missed to include the jQuery library
2. You are writing `<style>` tags in the CSS iframe.
3. Your code in the post is wrong. `click-row` is not an event, change to single `click`
4. If row is not coloured in yellow it's because the normal state is overriding the hover state. Just with `!important` in the style it works (or add more specificity as @j08691 said):

https://jsfiddle.net/xeqkb00c/1/

```
.hover { background-color:#FFFFCC !important; }
```

Comment: Points #1 and #2 are just related to the user not knowing how to use jsFiddle. I doubt that they're code has the same issues. and  most importantly, `!important` is almost always never the answer.

Comment: Allright, I agree in the `!important` carefully use. But is not the hell, `!important` is sometimes the solution. In this case is better take more specificity as you said in your answer, so I agree twice :)

Answer (score 3):

Here you go.

https://jsfiddle.net/wd4bs5vp/

```
$('tr').on('click', function() {
   $(this).toggleClass('click-row');
});
```

and...

```
 .click-row { background-color: green !important; }
 .hover { background-color:#FFFFCC !important; }
```

This fixes the hover issue and gets your onclick working the way you wanted.

Comment: Thank you for your help. The only thing is that only one row at atime should be green when clicked. Right now it seems as I can click on it and it stays green.

Comment: Updated with $('.click-row').removeClass('click-row');

https://jsfiddle.net/wd4bs5vp/1/

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget this :

```
   .hover { background-color:#FFFFCC !important; }
```

see https://jsfiddle.net/xeqkb00c/4/

Comment: `!important` is almost always never the answer